# Inconsistent colors with the same values in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color

I work with Illustrator in CMYK. I made a logo composed of several shapes and text.

I wanted to make a second version with little text inclined I made a copy of the logo and I tilted my first text. Both have the same color code but the logo at the bottom seems a little lighter compared to the from top even if they have the same color code.

What is the reason for this visual differences? And how can I correct it? (I absolutely need CMYK)

[image]

Comment: Your display. Flat screen need to be at a perfect 90 degree angle to be reliable and this little detail only can cause some colors to look different but they aren't. Especially on laptops... If you got an old display, it could be the problem too but usually it's what I mentioned before. One thing for sure, trust the NUMBERS and not your eyes. Just compare the color recipe and if the numbers match you know the issue is most likely hardware or on the chair ;)

Answer (score 2):

At first glance, they looked identical to me so I opened it in Photoshop CS6 and used the Eyedropper tool, it seems as though they are the exact same.
I'm not sure why you think it looks that different.

[image: the box in the middle is a sample of each stuck to each other]

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't add any screenshot, one can only guess. Maybe you did activate isolation mode? Click the 'back' arrow to exit it, and colors will look equal again...

[image]

Comment: I put a picture now. the difference is very small but visible

Comment: Exactly the same color values in the screenshot. I guess your display has some variations in brightness across the screen. You should always trust the CMYK values more than your display.

Comment: I agree with you. I thought it was the monitor, I tried on another PC and it was the same.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a single object filled with a solid color, and there are *no appearance settings* on the object or surrounding objects or layer...... it's the same color.

Any variation you see is due to either

1. A bad (or dirty) monitor display
2. A poor viewing angle to the monitor (common with some "gaming"
   monitors)
3. Perceptual difference due to surrounding ambient lighting
4. A smudge on your glasses
5. Too much alcohol or other substances
6. Alien brainwaves beamed in from Planet ¢å£∞¢¡å

Comment: As someone who's only had to wear glasses relatively recently, number 4 isn't that unlikely...

Comment: Well, to me.. they are *all* equally likely :) (and I too have had to resort to glasses in many instances this past year unfortunately )